# Show $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, improper-integrals

> Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} f(t)\cdot dt$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} f'^2(t)\cdot dt$ converge. Show $f$ is bounded.

My question is : if I use only the following  statements :
$f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} f(t)\cdot dt$ converges, it is enough to conclude $f$ is bounded, indeed $f(0)$ exists, and  $f(t)\underset{t\to +\infty}\to 0$ then with the extreme value theorem and the definition of the limit we can show $f$ is bounded.

Now if modify the statement of this problem

> Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}_+^*,\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} f(t)\cdot dt$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} f'^2(t)\cdot dt$ converge. Show $f$ is bounded.

Let $A:=\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} f'^2(t)\cdot dt$ and $\varepsilon>0$

$\displaystyle \int_x^y f'(t)\cdot dt =f(x)-f(y)$

then

$|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|\displaystyle \int_x^y f'(t)\cdot dt\right|\le\left|\displaystyle \int_x^y f'^2(t)\cdot dt\right|^{1/2}\cdot\quad\left|\displaystyle \int_x^y \;\; dt\right|^{1/2}<\sqrt{A}\sqrt{y-x}$

So I choose $\eta = \dfrac{\varepsilon^2}{A}$ we have $\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, |x-y|<\eta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ so $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$

Let $a<\eta$ for all $x\in(0,a) \quad f(a)-\varepsilon<f(x)<f(a)+\varepsilon$

With this same $\varepsilon$ there exists $c$ such that  $x>c$ we have $-\varepsilon<f(x)<\varepsilon$ and with the extrem value theorem we have $m<f(x)<M$ on $[a,c]$

With $M'=\max(f(a)+\varepsilon,\varepsilon,M)$ and $m'=\min(f(a)-\varepsilon,-\varepsilon,m)$

We have for all $x\in(0,+\infty) \quad m'<f(x)<M'$ the proof is complete $\square$

Is that all right?

Comment: your first argument is false. even if $f$ is integrable and in $C^1$m it doesn't mean that it is bounded. In particular, it is false that $f$ goes to zero at infinity

Comment: For a counter-example, take a function which is 0, but at every integer, it has an increasingly thin spike up to 1. If the width of the spikes decays sufficiently rapidly, this will still be integrable.

Comment: @Exodd Thanks for example : $$f : x\to \sin(x^2)$$

Comment: @Stu : Is it not supposed that $\int_0^{+\infty}|f(t)|dt $ converges ? It will be true with.

Comment: @Lucas  I don't think that will be true, see the answer of Alfred Yerger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to show $f$ tends to $0$ to prove it is bounded due to continuity on $[0,+\infty($ $(1)$. And for that since $f$ is integrable, it is sufficient to show it is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty($ $(2)$. It is a consequence of the inequality with $|f(x)-f(y)|$ in your post.

$(1)$ is pretty obvious. I let you $(2)$ to justify. Note that all kind of triangle functions are no longer valid as counter-example since you have proved $f$ is uniformly continuous.

---

Here is a solution :

$(1)$ is a easy consequence of preserving compactness by continuity.
For $(2)$, suppose $f$ does not tend to $0$ in $+\infty$ i.e. $\exists \epsilon, \forall A \in [0,+\infty(, \ \exists \ x≥A, |f(x)|≥ \epsilon$ $(*)$

But $f$ is uniformly continous on $[0,+\infty($, so $\exists \eta, \ \forall x,y \in [0,+\infty(, \ |x-y|≤\eta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|≤\epsilon/2$ $(**)$

Now, use $(*)$ to create a sequence $(x_n)$ that tends to $+\infty$ satisfying $\forall n, |f(x_n)|≥ \epsilon$

Then $(**)$ will contradict the fact $\int_{x_n}^{x_n + \eta}f(t)dt \to 0$ which is a consequence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)dt$ converges.

Indeed, $\forall n$, on $[x_n, x_n + \eta], |f|≥\epsilon/2$ so by continuity, $f≥\epsilon/2$ or $f≤-\epsilon/2$ hence $\forall n, |\int_{x_n}^{x_n + \eta}f(t)dt| ≥\eta *\epsilon/2 > 0$

Comment: Actually, it was not necessary that $\int_0^{+\infty}|f(t)|dt$ converges.

Comment: Note that all the problem was to prove $f \to 0$, it was not obvious a priori since it is very false in general.